# Recognizing correct brand image in scene with SURF method from brand images list

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, surf, object-recognition

Firstly i want to explain my problem with more detail;

1- I have many company brand(logo) image and I have one input which is a document image possibly from those companies.

2- I want to recognize that document image from logo.

For this aim i tried SURF method example of OpenCV it detects some points, in fact it gives better result while i give correct logo for correct document image, but I couldn't find a condition like;

```
if (something)
{
   this document reside in i'th logo
}
```

First Example result
[image: Here is positive sample]

Second Example result
[image: And here is negative sample]

As I shared above OpenCV's tutorial give a result but i couldn't develop a condition for object is founded or not. I need a opinion about this point.

I want to switch a flag to true while situation of first image detected.
By the way is there any solution for recognizing a brand(logo) with SURF or any other method ?

My code is almost same with [OpenCV Docs' Features2D + Homography to find a known object example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)